# DataTemplate depending on Page Orientation not changing WP7

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I need a listbox to show different info depending on page orientation, so started looking and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405098/how-to-change-the-item-template-of-list-box-depending-upon-the-current-orientati?answertab=votes#tab-top), , implemented it as follows:

Defined the DataTemplates in the resources section:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="LandscapeTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Name="txtNombre" Text="{Binding Path=nombre}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="0,10,0,0" FontSize="28" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Name="txtSep" Text=" - " TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="0,10,0,0" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Name="txtFecha" Text="{Binding Path=fecha_hora}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="0,10,0,0" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PortraitTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Name="txtNombre" Text="{Binding Path=nombre}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="0,10,0,0" FontSize="28" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Then use the VisualStateManager as follows:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="OrientationStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Landscape">
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="lista" 
                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="ItemTemplate">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" 
                                            Value="{StaticResource LandscapeTemplate}"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Default orientation of my app is Portrait, so I initially assign the PortraitTemplate to my list box

```
<ListBox x:Name="lista" 
                 SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged" 
                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PortraitTemplate}">
        </ListBox>
```

Then when testing the outcome, the template doesn't change. I would like to know what am I missing?. Or what else do I have to add to make the template change

Thanks in advance.

Additonal info: Also attempted to achieve what I need using this [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074447/changing-the-datatemplate-based-on-page-orientation)

Comment: Is your page's base class LayoutAwarePage ? As pointed out in the last line of the answer you have followed.

Comment: I tried to check, but wasn't sure how to check that.

Answer (score 0):

What finally worked:

In the application page constructor (In this case MainPage):

```
            this.OrientationChanged += new EventHandler<OrientationChangedEventArgs>(MainPage_OrientationChanged);
```

And add the handler method:

```
void MainPage_OrientationChanged(object sender, OrientationChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Orientation & PageOrientation.Landscape) > 0)
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Landscape", true);
            lista.ItemTemplate = LandscapeTemplate();
            lista.ItemsSource = null;
            List<StrTutoria> eventos = generarLista(asistiendo);
            this.lista.ItemsSource = eventos;
        }
        else
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Portrait", true);
            // Here goes code for portrait state
        }
    }
```

And LandscapeTemplate() implementation:

```
private DataTemplate LandscapeTemplate()
    {
        string xaml =
            @"<DataTemplate
                    xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""
                    xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"">
                    <StackPanel Orientation=""Horizontal"">
                        <TextBlock Name=""txtNombre"" Text=""{Binding Path=nombre}"" TextWrapping=""Wrap"" Padding=""0,10,0,0"" FontSize=""28"" VerticalAlignment=""Bottom""></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Name=""txtSep"" Text="" - "" TextWrapping=""Wrap"" Padding=""0,10,0,0"" FontSize=""22"" VerticalAlignment=""Bottom""></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Name=""txtFecha"" Text=""{Binding Path=fecha_hora}"" TextWrapping=""Wrap"" Padding=""0,10,0,0"" FontSize=""22"" VerticalAlignment=""Bottom""></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>";
        DataTemplate dt = (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(xaml);
        return dt;
    }
```

The final part of the solution was available [here](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/wp7-dynamically-generating-datatemplate-in-code)